Как из standalone google script вызвать скрипт, находящийсяв гугл таблице?
Есть гугл таблица со скриптом на определенные действия и есть приложение AppSheet, из которого необходимо выполнять в таблице те же действия.
Доступ к таблице  из standalone происходит  через SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl().
Не придумал ничего  лучше, чем хранить две копии скрипта (в таблице и файле standalone).
Можно ли из standalone скрипта вызвать скрипт в таблице?

Разверни табличный скрипт как библиотеку и подсоедини эту библиотеку к standalone скрипту. Можно даже в табличном скрипте написать специальную функцию, которая будет обрабатывать вызовы внешнего скрипта

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
